# Reading data from FileOutputStream adds "null" to my data

Tags: android, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

In my first `Activity` I'm saving coordinates in `FileOutputStream` then in another `Activity` I read the data. But it always adds "null" to my coordinations. Am I doing something wrong?

**Activity 1 where I write data to FileOutPutStream**

```
FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        String lat, lng;
        lat = String.valueOf(location_latitude);
        lng = String.valueOf(location_longitude);

        fos = openFileOutput("my_latitude", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(lat.getBytes());
        fos.close();

        fos = openFileOutput("my_longitude", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(lng.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        Log.e("SPLASHER",lat);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

**Activity 2 where I read data**

```
private void getLocations() {
        String[] locations = getApplicationContext().fileList();
        for (int i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

            FileInputStream fis;

            try {
                fis = openFileInput(locations[i]);
                byte[] input = new byte[fis.available()];

                if (locations[0].equals("my_latitude")) {

                while (fis.read(input) != -1) {
                    myLat += new String(input);
                    // int start = myLat.indexOf("null");
                    // String suffix = myLat.substring(start);
                    myLat.replaceAll(".*?null", "");
                    Log.e("READING", myLat);
                    }
                }
                fis.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Log.e("LOCATTTIEEEE", locations[i]);

        }
    }
```

**Log**

```
06-07 01:28:10.565: E/SPLASHER(9769): 51.1878003
06-07 01:25:41.660: E/YESSIR(6359): null51.1878167
```

So I think the writing is okay, but something is going wrong in the reading part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the error..

I had to initialize `String lat, lng;` like so `String lat="", lng="";`

This solved my problem!!